# How can I hide all images and only show the selected ones that I want displayed?

Tags: ios, swift

For this program I am trying to get the difficulty of the class to be represented in the form of stars, which are all their own separate image view. I have got the rest of the project working but I am just completely lost on how to get a certain amount of the stars to show and the rest to be hidden.

For example, like in the picture, if CSC 185 is selected then 2 stars should be displayed. What function can I use to make it so this is the case?

I have tried making if statements for each different segmented control option to hard code the intended amount of stars but I believe the syntax is wrong. I have only ever taken Java classes so the statements that I was trying to make did not relay correctly is Swift.

[Example of the interface I have set already.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnBs5.png)

Here is the code that I currently have to display the correct image view for the class notes and the correct label for the class:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var classTypeSeg: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var courseLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var courseNotesImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstStar: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondStar: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdStar: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var fouthStar: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var fifthStar: UIImageView!
    var curCourse = "CSC 185"
    
    //This will list all of the different courses
    let courses: [String] = [
        "CSC 195",
        "CSC 190",
        "CSC 191",
        "CSC 308",
        "CSC 310",
        "CSC 313",
        "CSC 340",
    ]
    
    //This will make the picture for the notes represent the correct class
    @IBAction func classChoiceIsMade(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        courseNotesImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(curCourse).jpg")
    }
    
    //This will change the label to represent the correct class
    @IBAction func labelChoiceIsMade(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        curCourse = sender.titleForSegment(at: sender.selectedSegmentIndex)!
        courseLabel.text = (curCourse)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        classTypeSeg.removeAllSegments()
        for i in 0..<courses.count {
            classTypeSeg.insertSegment(withTitle: courses[i], at: i, animated: false)
        }
        classTypeSeg.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it will be much earlier to use [Cosmos](https://github.com/evgenyneu/Cosmos) and in this case you need just set rating property like `cosmosView.rating = 4`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an array of strings, have an array of structs that includes a star count property

```
struct CSClass {
    let level: String
    let numStars: Int
}


let courses: [CSClass] = [
   CSClass(level: "CSC 190", numStars: 1),
   CSClass(level: "CSC 195", numStars: 2),
   //And so on for all the different classes
   ]
```

Then use an index into the array instead of a segment title to keep track of the selelected class, and just use

```
courses[selectedCourse].level
```

and

```
courses[selectedCourse].numStars
```

To get to the course level and number of stars for each course.

Answer (score 0):

Use the structure from Duncan C's answer to manage the data.

Then, to show *n* number of stars...

- Put your "star" imageViews in a horizontal `UIStackView`.
- Loop through them, and for each one, set `.isHidden = true` if its position is greater than the number of stars to show.

So, assuming you've added 5 "star" imageViews to a stack view, and connected it via:

```
@IBOutlet var starsStackView: UIStackView!
```

You can call this func to show the correct number of stars:

```
func updateStars(_ numberOfStarsToShow: Int) {
    for i in 0..<starsStackView.arrangedSubviews.count {
        starsStackView.arrangedSubviews[i].isHidden = i + 1 > numberOfStarsToShow
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the example provided as well.

Comment: Using a stack view would cause the stars to be centered. Typically for a rating system, you want the stars to stay in a fixed position. Instead of a stack view I would suggest just putting them in fixed locations inside a view, adding their outlets to an array, and using a for loop like you describe.